# Unresolved reference: findViewById in recyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to use an imageView to which an image will be loaded. so, to use the imageView i'm using findViewId but it gives an error: Unresolved reference: findViewById.
imageView's id is ivArticleImage

NewsAdapter.kt:

```
package com.example.newsapp_mvvm.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.newsapp_mvvm.R
import com.example.newsapp_mvvm.models.Article


class NewsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

    val articleImage= findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivArticleImage)

    inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private val differCallback= object:DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url==newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem==newItem
        }
    }

    val differ=AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_article_preview,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = differ.currentList[position]

        holder.itemView.apply {
            Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(articleImage)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }
}
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to solve this error, you have defined your view out side of holder. you can define it into the onbindholder method and you can use that imageview to your adapter.

```
package com.example.newsapp_mvvm.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.newsapp_mvvm.R
import com.example.newsapp_mvvm.models.Article


class NewsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var articleImage:ImageView

    inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private val differCallback= object:DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url==newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem==newItem
        }
    }

    val differ=AsyncListDiffer(this,differCallback)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_article_preview,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = differ.currentList[position]

    articleImage= holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivArticleImage)

        holder.itemView.apply {
            Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(articleImage)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution

Comment: is there any way we can define the view in ArticleViewHolder?

Comment: Yes you can define your view into viewholder class like this                                     inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)  {     articleImage= itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivArticleImage)
   }

Comment: yes i was thinking of doing this way, thanks for your clarification

Comment: yes, kindly accept the answer with upvote.